# Gawk find pattern quotes with zeros fails

Tags: gawk

I am busy writing a AWK script to match a specific pattern in a string. Here is the string:

```
~SD0~ 2 (239) B="004662" N=165 U=2 <REJS> R=72
```

And I am using the following match-pattern:

```
if (match ($0, /B=\"([0-9]+)\"/) > 0)
```

This match-pattern fails as long as there is: **B="004662"** in the string but the match-pattern matches when the number not starts with a '0' after the double quotes e.g.: **B="104662"**. Is seems the combination "0 (double quotes with a zero) is not a 'good' combination.

All tips and hints to overcome this problem are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

These approaches all works for me using `GNU Awk 4.0.1`

```
/B=\"[0-9]+\"/ {
  print "match!"
}

{
  if (match($0, /B=\"([0-9]+)\"/) > 0) {
    print "also match"
  }
  else {
    print "no match"
  }
}

match($0, /B=\"([0-9]+)\"/,a) { print a[1] }
```

output:

```
match!
also match
0004662
```